# npm install fails on serverless project on my mac, what is the cause?

Tags: node.js, npm, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm attempting to go through a tutorial on serverless projects, yet have hit a point where I can't continue. I've installed the 'serverless' package and used it to setup the initial project structure using `serverless install --url https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-nodejs-starter --name notes-app-api`

That appeared to succeed, the next step is to run 'npm install' however this is failing with the messages below.  Any suggestions most welcome as to how to diagnose the cause.

```
npm install

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /Development/serverless/myproject/myproject-api/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@10.5.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@10.5.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance


xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why an immediate downvote with no comment? If you're unable to assist, don't and move on else leave some constructive message.

Comment: Upvoted your question. Have the same issue..

Comment: @JamesJ. Please check my answer below. it was a simple fix in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution I found was to specify an updated version of the fsevents library.  After adding `"fsevents": "^1.2.4",` to the devDependencies section in package.json, the project was able to build.